# Создаю десктопное приложение на JavaFX по считыванию RFID. Подскажите как можно добавлять label во время работы программы?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Нужно написать десктопное приложение для считывания rfid, с запуском reader никаких проблем нет, то когда reader.open() я при обнаружении могу получить код и вывести на консоль, а как так сделать в javafx, если у кого нить есть может пример, необязательно такой, допустим при нажатии на кнопку создавался label

Comment: Можно создавать скрытый по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FXMLExampleController {
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    @FXML
    protected void handleSomeButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        gridPane.add(new Label("Test"), 0, 0);
    }
}
```